# DataGrid remembers old selection even if we unselect all item(s)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my WPF `DataGrid` I have 4 rows. First, I select `row 1` and then unselect it (so no item is selected now). Then, I press Shift + select `row 2` and I see both `row 1` and `row 2` were selected. It's like the grid still remembers the previously selected `row 1` even if we unselect it.

I don't want the grid to remember the old selection. How is this possible?

Comment: when you deselect, where is your tab selection ?

Comment: Please show the xaml-definition of your `DataGrid`

Comment: How do you unselect the 1st row?

Answer (score 1):

Set the **SelectionMode property to Single.**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgrSample" SelectionMode="Single"/>
```